# Using std::wstring in WinAPI function: not all text sent

Tags: c++, winapi

When HTTP posting data; if I use `std::wstring` as a parameter not all the text is posted. But if I use a standard TCHAR array then all the text is posted. Why is this happening and how can I keep using the `std::wstring`?

```
// wont compile unless cast to LPVOID and not all data is sent.
HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, -1, (LPVOID)fData.c_str(), fData.size()); 

// successfully sends all fData text
TCHAR s[1024] = {0};
_tcscpy(s, fData.c_str());
HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, -1, s, sizeof(s));
```

Comment: "wont compile unless cast to LPVOID" tells you that you have the wrong types.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf the functions 4th parameter expects a `LPVOID`, ie, void pointer. A void pointer can be any type.

Comment: `HttpSendRequest` should use `fData.size() * 2` if that's `std::wstring`

Comment: @JakeM: Any pointer `T*` converts implicitly to `void*`, no cast required. So presumably this is a `const_cast` then. You could have included that information: the comment indicated wrong type.

Comment: Are you sure you actually want to send `fData` "as is"? `HttpSendRequest` does not perform any translation of that parameter, it just sends the raw bytes, so you are assuming that on the other end there's somebody who is expecting to receive UTF-16 data, which is a bit unusual in the HTTP world.

Answer (score 1):

The [HttpSendRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384247.aspx) documentation says:

> dwOptionalLength [in]
>   The size of the optional data, **in bytes**. This parameter can be zero if there is no optional data to send.

`size()` returns the number of character elements in the string, not the size of the string in bytes. The byte size of a `wchar_t` on Windows is 2, so instead of this:

```
HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, -1, (LPVOID)fData.c_str(), fData.size());
```

It needs to be this:

```
HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, -1, (LPVOID)fData.c_str(), fData.size() * sizeof(wchar_t));
```

Comment: I am sure that works for you but there is no relation between `TCHAR` and `std::wstring`, or whatever `fData` is supposed to be.

Comment: I fixed the answer. There is no place for `TCHAR` here.